# Simple Windows Server 2008 Backup Script

Tags: batch-file, backup, windows-server-2008

I made simple Win Serv 2008 R2 backup script (in addtion for built-in)

```
wbadmin start backup -backupTarget:\\winee\vhds\backup\ -allcritical -systemState -include:c: -quiet
for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%a in ('date /T') do set datestr=%%a
mkdir C:\backup\%datestr%
XCOPY "Z:\backup\" "C:\backup\%datestr%"
```

In simple words - I want to copy all folders and files inside Z:\backup (mapped disk - it equals \winee\vhds\backup to another folder named automatically as current DATE. Only last part do not work - it says Incorrent path.
What should I change?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Result of `date /T` command might contain reserved characters, cf. [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
< (less than)
> (greater than)
: (colon)
" (double quote)
/ (forward slash)
\ (backslash)
| (vertical bar or pipe)
? (question mark)
* (asterisk)
```

For instance, if your date contains `/` (forward slash), [replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) it e.g. with `_` (low line, underscore) as follows.

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%a in ('date /T') do set "datestr=%%a"
set "datestr=%datestr:/=_%"
     rem add next line, cf. **edit**
set "datestr=%datestr: =%"
mkdir "C:\backup\%datestr%"
```

(Note and adhere proper spacing and `"` quotation). By [this resource: `mkdir`](http://ss64.com/nt/md.html), you should avoid using the following characters in folder names: `© ® " - & ' ^ ( )` and `@`  as they are known to cause problems.

**Edit** According to your comment on `space`, you are right. I didn't see or even suspect it before now, sorry. Compare next (pure CLI) output:

```
==>for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %a in ('date /T') do @echo [%a]
[06.03.2015 ]

==>for /f "tokens=1" %a in ('date /T') do @echo [%a]
[06.03.2015]

==>echo [%date%]
[06.03.2015]

==>
```

Thus, add `set "datestr=%datestr: =%"` or,  instead of

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%a in ('date /T') do set "datestr=%%a"
set "datestr=%datestr:/=_%"
set "datestr=%datestr: =%"
```

just use simply

```
"datestr=%date:/=_%"
```

In fact, I don't know your *locale* `%date%` format; it might fail with `mar 6, 2015` and like…

Comment: I still have error. I think the problem is in SET. It creates folder with date like this: "2015-03-06 " - with space.